# How do I check when a Youtube video finished playing in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I embedded a Shockwave Player into a C# .NET application.
Is it possible to get an event fired from the Youtube player when the video currently played finished playing?
Youtube APIs give me nothing of the sort, same for the Shockwave Player embedded into the application. The only events that get fired are in Javascript, but I can't find a way to forward them to the application itself.

Comment: It's definitely not possible to detect this unless you handle the JavaScript events in some way. There's nothing in the Data API (which is what you're using from C#) that would support it.

Comment: @JeffPosnick is right. You will need to do either AJAX or location.href change in order to let the backend know that has finished. You know the differences between back and front end right?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Posnick and Tom Roggero mentioned, you need to do this in javascript, but nothing should stop you from letting javascript pinging information back to your server on that event.

The event you are looking for is the onStageChange, when state turns to 0 (end) the playback has reached the end of the video. In your javascript event handler you can do an ajax request back to the server.

Here's a neat page to play around with the Youtube Player API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo And an API reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status